# Laravel Controller Filters: Before filter on a particular method does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-filters

Code in my controller file is something similar to this:

```
public function __construct(Student $student)
{
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', ['on' => 'show']);
}
```

It does not work.

But the followings work:

```
public function __construct(Student $student)
{
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', ['except' => 'show']);
}
```

and

```
public function __construct(Student $student)
{
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', ['only' => 'show']);
}
```

So, what's the problem with `'on'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `on` filter runs if the request has a specific **HTTP verb** (aka request method). So options are `post`, `get`, `put` etc.

For assigning a filter for an action, `except` and `only` are all you need.

Comment: Ok. So, according to you `show` method is `get students/{id}` and update method is `post students/{id}`, so it's not working on `show` method?

Comment: That's right. (Except update is in fact `put`. `post` calls the `store` method)

Comment: Yes, it's `put students/{id}` for update. Now I am wondering why do they use `put students/{id}` instead `post students/{id}`, even though it's unrelated to the question ;-)

Comment: Well that's kind of the standard setup for RESTful API's. `get` to retrieve resources. `post` to create new resources. `put` to update existing ones and `delete`, obviously, to delete them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer on that comment.